# Numpy parallel indexing using np.ix_

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, parallel-processing

I have a Python script in which I heavily use numpy. I recently learned a bit more about numpys inherent parallelisation, and that one should avoid big for-loops with numpy and instead rely on implicit parallel indexing.

I have a very huge for-loop in my script (which actually contains another for-loop). That loop splits data in training and test sets, manipulates each set independently in some way, fits models and repeats. It is an n-repeated k-fold.

However, the script is very slow and seems to cause memory leakage if n and k are big. I think this is also due to the huge for loop. So I wanted to get rid of the for loop and use the splits in a parallel fashion. However, I don't succeed. Here is what is happening in my script:

This first bit is generic:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import RepeatedKFold
import ... 
#Some data is imported, functions defined, variables pre-allocated.

number_conditions = 10 #Usually bigger.
output = np.array(number_conditions, number_conditions) #This contains real data, though.
outer_k = 5
outer_reps = 1 # usually much higher
outer_rkf = RepeatedKFold(n_splits=outer_k, n_repeats=outer_reps)


array_for_indices = list(range(number_conditions))
```

This is the non-efficient for-loop version:

```
for train_indices, test_indices in outer_rkf.split(array_for_indices):

    ixgrid_train = np.ix_(train_indices, train_indices)
    output_train = output[ixgrid_train]

    ixgrid_test = np.ix_(test_indices, test_indices)
    output_test = output[ixgrid_test]

    ...
```

This is followed by some heavy data manipulation and another nested for-loop, and is then repeated (outer_k*outer_reps) times.

I wanted to parallelise this and tried this:

```
outer_split_1, outer_split_2, outer_split_3, outer_split_4, outer_split_5 = outer_rkf.split(array_for_indices)

index = np.array([outer_split_1, outer_split_2, outer_split_3, outer_split_4, outer_split_5])

all_train_inds = index[:, 0]
all_test_inds = index[:, 1]

ixgrid_train = np.ix_(all_train_inds, all_train_inds)
output_train = output[ixgrid_train]
```

But the last line gives me

> IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type

Which kind of makes sense to me: in the for-loop version, *ixgrid_train* is a tuple with two arrays of ints. In the latter version, it is a tuple with two arrays of objects, which in turn hold arrays.

I tried making *index* not an array but a tuple, or a list, and tried to index *index* on different ways (writing this shows me that *index* is probably a name to-be-improved). However, I never achieve what I want: that *output_train* contains not just the desired data for one split, but for all, and gets it assigned in one go.

At the base of my problem is that I don't know how to basically increase the dimensionality of what I am doing. I imagine that I need to transfer the dimension I am looping over in the loop-version into a dimension of the objects I am operating on, but I don't know how to do this which yields actual parallellism. Especially, since tuple confuse me.

How can I achieve what I want: create all indices for all folds at once, and then assign all selected data for each fold at once, so that I can carry on working with that in parallel later on?

I am grateful for any input! :)

Comment: How about giving this question more focus?  I can't picture what's going on just by reading your description.  I can guess the iterative `ixgrid_train` is. but can't picture the second.

Answer (score 0):

Does this illustrate your problem:

```
In [186]: idx=np.array([np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([4,5])])                             
In [187]: idx                                                                            
Out[187]: array([array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5])], dtype=object)
In [188]: np.ix_(idx,idx)                                                                
Out[188]: 
(array([[array([1, 2, 3])],
        [array([4, 5])]], dtype=object),
 array([[array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5])]], dtype=object))
In [189]: np.ones((10,10),int)[_]                                                        
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-189-fa4d7e0befc5> in <module>
----> 1 np.ones((10,10),int)[_]
```

while the iterative case is

```
In [190]: [np.arange(100).reshape(10,10)[np.ix_(row,row)] for row in idx]                
Out[190]: 
[array([[11, 12, 13],
        [21, 22, 23],
        [31, 32, 33]]),
 array([[44, 45],
        [54, 55]])]
```

Indexing different size blocks (possibly overlapping) means this is impossible to cast as one n-d indexing operation.

```
IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

You don't want a union-block like

```
In [192]: np.arange(100).reshape(10,10)[np.ix_([1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5])]                 
Out[192]: 
array([[11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [21, 22, 23, 24, 25],
       [31, 32, 33, 34, 35],
       [41, 42, 43, 44, 45],
       [51, 52, 53, 54, 55]])
```

nor do you want the flattened elements:

```
In [193]: np.hstack([i.ravel() for i in _190])                                           
Out[193]: array([11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23, 31, 32, 33, 44, 45, 54, 55])
```